# c# Mono App in Linux/Raspbian can't read from serial port while a socket is being served (can write / but the serial input buffer reports 0 bytes)

Tags: c#, sockets, mono, serial-port, raspbian

I have a c# mono application to be mounted on Linux/raspbian (raspberry pi 3 model b+) , that application access the serial port in order to communicate with an special device (wiegand card reader) to get information about the reading status and get the information on the card. All the serial communication is going fine except by:

This application also needs to act as SERVER in order that other computers can request information about the serial-device.   My trouble is that when the application is serving a socket request its block the serial input buffer (although i can write to serial port) i can't read the input buffer because it always reports 0 bytes (during the socket operation is alive), when the socket operations ends the serial input (response from the weigand interface) is queued again into the input buffer, That to late because the socket operation has ended and i need to return the serial-data in the socket result.

If i made the socket request from the same machine acting as server (server and client on the same raspberry pi) all of this works fine and I'm able to read the serial port during the socket operation, **the trouble is when the socket request is coming from another machine in the network.**

I don't know the reason about this behavior, because i can write to the serial port while a socket request is being server, but i can't read the serial port (because it is reporting 0 bytes) while the socket operation is in progress.. the serial information is being posted to the input buffer until the socket operations ends.

Can you give any lights to fix this trouble ??  maybe i need to configure something on the Linux system, or maybe this could be a bug in mono ??

Can you advice on this or make suggestions in order to improve the process, i need to return in the socket operation the results of reading the serial port.

Thanks

Comment: to make the socket request I'm using the  SERVICEWIRE library.

Comment: if i run the application on windows side i don't have trouble to read serial put while the socked i being serviced, so this issue is just on the side of MONO/RASPBERRY PI3 B+.  Please let me know if you know any fix on the LINUX/RASPBIAN SIDE.

Comment: what version of mono is this?

Comment: mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 5.14.0.177 (tarball Mon Aug  6 10:53:50 UTC 2018)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
 TLS:           __thread
 SIGSEGV:       normal
 Notifications: epoll
 Architecture:  armel,vfp+hard
 Disabled:      none
 Misc:          softdebug 
 Interpreter:   yes
 LLVM:          yes(3.6.0svn-mono-/)
 GC:            sgen (concurrent by default)